# _TypeError (Null check operator used on a null value)

Tags: android, flutter, exception

This exception appear when i try to use this

```
Image.asset(_image! ,
                    height: 280,),
```

and I have this

```
const PagesItem({super.key, this.title, this.description, this.emailadress,  this.image});
final String? title;
final String? emailadress;
  final String? description;
  final String? image  ;
```

Can i know what's the problem and the solution please ?

This work to me in the first page and not her so what's the problem please

Comment: `image!` asserts that `image` cannot be `null`, but you have not guaranteed that, and the `PagesItem` constructor even makes it optional (which will initialize it to `null` by default).

Answer (score 0):

```
Image.asset(_image ?? _defaultImage ,height: 280)
```

Here you need to pass a default image if the image is not available

or

```
if(_image != null) Image.asset(_image! ,height: 280)
```

In this line your widget doesn't build if image is null